# How can I (or a company) get fake Test Accounts for a Banking website without consulting the bank?

Tags: qa-role

Anybody know how I can get a fake test account for a Banking Website without consulting the bank?

Comment: You'll want to contact the bank and have them set up an account for you.

Comment: Are you looking for username/password account, or just test account numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There are various possibilities out there. *Fake credit card numbers* are reserved especially for testing.

[Paypal](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm) has some online info on how to handle testing.

[Mangopay](https://docs.mangopay.com/api-references/test-payment/) has a sandbox also supporting bank account numbers. Likewise [Checkfront](https://www.checkfront.com/support/test-gateway) has a special gateway.

[Google](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) also has special support for testing Google Play transactions without actually transferring money, as has [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/).

If you need to test against a custom api of a single bank they *should* have something similar for you.

Good luck!